# Issue with sed search and replace with brackets

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I am replacing the below file (sample.txt):

```
![top command output linux](./img/wp-content-uploads-2022-04-top-command-output-linux.jpg)
```

with:

```
{{< image alt="top command output linux" src="/images/post/wp-content-uploads-2022-04-top-command-output-linux.jpg" >}}
```

Also, I need to do an inline file replacement. Here is what I have done:

```
sed -i -e 's/^!\[/\{\{< image alt="/g' sample.txt
```

Output:

```
{{< image alt="top command output linux](./img/wp-content-uploads-2022-04-top-command-output-linux.jpg)
```

But when I try to replace `](./img` with `" src="/images/post`, I am getting errors. I have tried below, but it does not change anything:

```
sed -i -e 's/^!\[/\{\{< image alt="/g' -e 's/\]\\(.\/img/\" src=\"\/images\/post/g' sample.txt
```

So basically the problem is with the 2nd substitution:

```
's/\]\\(.\/img/\" src=\"\/images\/post/g'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a POSIX BRE based solution like

```sh
sed -i 's~!\[\([^][]*\)](\./img/\([^()]*\))~{{< image alt="\1" src="/images/post/\2" >}}~g' file
```

Or, with POSIX ERE:

```sh
sed -i -E 's~!\[([^][]*)]\(\./img/([^()]*)\)~{{< image alt="\1" src="/images/post/\2" >}}~g' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/ILt9Qa). The regex works like is [shown here](https://regex101.com/r/ZdPRKL/1).

*Details*:

- `!\[` - a `![` substring
- `\([^][]*\)` - Group 1 (`\1`, POSIX BRE, in POSIX ERE, the capturing parentheses must be escaped): zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `](\./img/` - `](./img/` substring (in POSIX ERE, `(` must be escaped)
- `\([^()]*\)` - Group 2 (`\2`): any zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `)` - a `)` char (in POSIX BRE) (in POSIX ERE it must be escaped).

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting single `awk` command to do all the transformations.

```
 awk -F"[\\\]\\\[\\\(\\\)]" '{sub("./img","/images/post");printf("{{< image alt=\"%s\" src=\"%s\" >}}", $2, $4)}' <<< $(echo '![top command output linux](./img/wp-content-uploads-2022-04-top-command-output-linux.jpg)')
```

Results:

```
{{< image alt="top command output linux" src="/images/post/wp-content-uploads-2022-04-top-command-output-linux.jpg" >}}
```

Comment: I need an in-place replacement in the same file. So I think I have to use sed only.